# How to run inline code within a logic app?

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-logic-apps

I have 2 variables json array

```
variable1 = 
[
  {
    "CurrentDate": "2019-05-11",
    "CurrentTime": "01:09:14",
    "tablename": "A"
  },
  {
    "CurrentDate": "2019-05-11",
    "CurrentTime": "01:11:14",
    "tablename": "Z"
  }
]

variable2 =
[
  {
    "A": "Topic1"
  },
  {
    "Z": "Topic2"
  }
]
```

Now I want to compare `tablename` value with `variable2` key and if it matches pass `variable2` value to next step.

For example, in `variable1` for each loop it will take tablename value `A` checks with `variable2` array each element and key matches for `A` then I need to pass its value as `Topic1` to next step or assign a value to global variable. Same happens for all the elements one by one.

I tried using 2 foreach but unable to assign values. How can I write an expression to match value and assign global value after match to variable?

If this is not possible I will modify variable2 like

```
  variable2 =
    [
     "A" , "B"
    ] and add equal expression like   "equals": [
                                                "@items('For_each')?['tablename']",
                                                "@items('For_each_2')"
                                            ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now run code inside a logic app (limited to javascript for the moment):

[image]

See the documentation for more information:

[Add and run code snippets by using inline code in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code).

This should do the trick for you.